# How would I use the same viewcontroller, but pass different information through it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-location

so, my current problem is as follows.

I would like to essentially use my current viewcontroller, but change the location settings somewhere else within the app and have the data pass though the viewcontroller with the updated location information.

I'll elaborate. I'm currently utilizing the following code for reverse geocoding, and obtaining the users location.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if(locations.count > 0){


        let location = locations[0] as! CLLocation

        //            println(location.coordinate)


        if let currentLocatino = currLocation {
            if CLLocation(latitude: currentLocatino.latitude, longitude: currentLocatino.longitude).distanceFromLocation(location) > 500 {
                currLocation = location.coordinate
                self.skip = 0
                self.loadObjects()

            }
        }
        else {
            currLocation = location.coordinate
            self.skip = 0
            self.loadObjects()
        }


        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: currLocation!.latitude, longitude: currLocation!.longitude), completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in


            if error != nil {
                println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let date = NSDate()
                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
                formatter.stringFromDate(date)
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark


                var testifempty = "\(pm.subLocality)"
                if testifempty == "nil"
                {
                    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    if let lbutton = self.lbutton{
                        lbutton.text = "Hey " + "\(pm.locality)" //+ "\n" + formatter.stringFromDate(date)


                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    if let lbutton = self.lbutton {
                        lbutton.text = "Hey " + "\(pm.subLocality)\n" // + formatter.stringFromDate(date)
                    }

                }
            }

            else {
                println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })

    } else {


        println("Cannot fetch your location")

    }

}
```

What I would like, it to essentially pass through a NEW location and set a boolean of sorts so that if said boolean is set to false, the NEW location information is passed through the app.

I'm thinking about using a switch on the main viewcontroller, and changing the location on a secondary viewcontroller.

I'm sorry if this is a long post, but I feel as though I'm right on the edge of figuring out how to do this but I need to be sure I'm going in the right direction.

Maybe I could use a mapkit and use annotations?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a view of any type to pass or hold information. A switch (like a `UISwitch`) should represent some other data in a graphical way for the user.

If you're new to mobile development, I'd recommend taking a look at the MVC design pattern. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html), are a [couple](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns) different [resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to get you started on that.

If you need to keep some data somewhere in your app that you can access from any class (viewController, view, custom object, etc.) then a [Singleton](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/) would be a great solution. You can have map data that comes in be accessible across the entire app, you can store variables and be able to re-assign them from other classes, and you always end up with only one instance so your logical wires never get crossed.

Singletons get use fairly often, so I'd recommend looking at what the implementation code looks like and getting familiar with it. [Here's a brief example of an implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/80271/62864).

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, the delegation pattern seems like the most appropriate choice.

If you create a protocol for your primary view controller that declares a method to update its data, such as `locationDidUpdate:`, then the primary view controller can be set as a delegate of the secondary view controller. The secondary view controller can then call this delegate method and update the primary view controller with new data.

As an example, a protocol can be declared in your first view controller like:

```
protocol LocationViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func locationDidUpdate(location: CLLocation)
}
```

Then have your secondary view controller conform to the protocol and create a delegate property:

```
weak var delegate: LocationViewControllerDelegate?
```

When you need to update the location, call the delegate method with:

```
delegate.locationDidUpdate(myNewLocation)
```

Having a protocol for managing event-based updates is an advantage, in general, because it provides a clear contract that can easily be implemented by other classes.

Comment: Yes, this is a very good route, not too complex either. I'll let you know how it goes in a little bit, and I'll probably have a few more questions.

Comment: I already have a question, where would I put the delegate method, in the first view controller correct?

Comment: @JamesChen, yes, you can declare your protocol in your first view controller.